Azure VM Managed Run Command - RunAsUser and RunAsPassword arguments are ignored
I'm trying to execute a powershell script through the managed run commands.
It is working as expected, but when I add RunAsUser and RunAsPassword arguments as documented here, these arguments are ignored and the script still executes as systemprofile user.
I verified, the specified user has Virtual Machine Administrator Login role, so it has access to the VM and to any location on this one.
Am I missing something?

Can you log in to the VM using these credentials?

Also any error message, logs ?

@Thomas yes I already logged in with these credentials and executed the same script successfully

When you use the RunAsUser and RunAsPassword arguments, do you receive any errors?If so, kindly provide the error details.

@VenkatV the error I get is related to my PATH not being the one the user has when logged with the user. As the PATH is the one of systemprofile user, my pyenw-win path is not loaded. When logged into the VM with the user I don't have this issue

To workaround the problem, I added the pyenv-win path to the PATH before running the script, and it worked for python to be able to execute. But I get other errors during execution. To be more specific, I script SAP through python and win32 lib, and I don't receive the SAP client Object when running through run command, but this works perfectly when running the script from logged user

Can you please share the managed ru-_command code you are using with an error screenshot?

Hi @VenkatV, there's no need to share this, the error is that when the SAP GUI is opened, it is opened as if it was the system user that opens it, not as the runas user. Honestly as of now, I can't see any difference when running the command by specifying (or not) the RunAsUser and RunAsPassword arguments, everything is processed as the system user. I want SAP program to opens like if it was opened by the RunAsUser specified user and that is not the case. No need to share errors, as the error is just python not able to reach the login into SAP

Do you mean the path will be accessible only when SAP GUI is opened with the systemuser?

No, I mean I want SAP GUI to be opened as if the user that opens it is the user specified in RanAsUser argument. This is not what happens as the SAP GUI is always opened as if it was opened by the system user when opening it through run command. This cause the SAP GUI to not be usable by my script

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The Managed Run Command doesn't seem to work as it should. When running through RunAsUser and RunAsPassword, the command is always called as if the system user called it (so the specified user context is not loaded). I used PsExec of PSTools as a workaround, by getting the user password from key vault directly from the VM powershell script.
There's also another problem I found, when running the managed run command through RunAsUser, the command parameters are not taken into account. Here's a link to an opened issue I found.
It would be great to have something working as described in the microsoft azure documentation for the managed run command, hopefully the azure team will release a fix in the future?
